# The adapter was unable to infer a handler to use for the event. This is likely related to how the Lambda function was invoked

Tags: python, aws-lambda, fastapi, mangum

I am stuck in this error and is clueless.  Trying to run a code on aws lambda, but i am testing it locally
Here is code
app.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import uvicorn

app=FastAPI()
handler=Mangum(app)

class TextModel(BaseModel):
    text: str

@app.post("/")
def process_data(text: TextModel):
   
    return JSONResponse({'result':text.text})


if __name__ == "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=9000)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" -U 
#--no-cache-dir

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

When i test it locally be following command, i got the error

```
curl "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"text":"hello world!"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error message.

For me the problem was an unused annotation before commented out code:

```
@app.middleware("http")
# async def log_context(request: Request, call_next: Any) -> Any:
#

def handler(event: dict[str, Any], context: LambdaContext) -> dict[str, Any]:
    ues_logger.log(f"event: {event}")
    ues_logger.log(f"context: {context}")
    asgi_handler = Mangum(app)
    return asgi_handler(event, context)
```

Your code looks fine, but I would try to define your `handler` at the end of your module.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import uvicorn

app=FastAPI()

class TextModel(BaseModel):
    text: str

@app.post("/")
def process_data(text: TextModel):
   
    return JSONResponse({'result':text.text})

handler=Mangum(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=9000)
```